# how to find root cause of stuck thread from thread dump report?

Tags: java, multithreading, weblogic, okhttp, weblogic12c

I have a live application deployed on a #Weblogic (12c) application server that has 4 stuck threads right now. it occurred after more than one month of uptime.
`extra info:`
as the thread dump shows the problem occurs in my "postSMS" method that uses okhttp library to call another RESTFull service:
here is my method body:

```
@POST
@Path("postSMS")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8"})
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN + ";charset=utf-8"})
public void postSMS(SMSObjMMC objMMC, @Suspended AsyncResponse response, @Context final HttpServletRequest request) {
    if (objMMC != null && objMMC.getOpCode() == null) {
        objMMC.setOpCode(EnumSpcOpcode.FROM_MMC.getOpcode());
    }
    try {
        RestConstant.setTimeoutToRequest(AppConstants.HOST_SPEC.getMMC().getClientTimeOut(), response);
        String remoteAddr = request.getRemoteAddr() + "-" + request.getRemotePort();
        String remoteHost = request.getRemoteHost();
        HttpHeaderRequest httpHeader = HttpHelper.extractHttpHeaderFromRequest(request);//Save Header
        SmsOut smsOut = new SmsOut(ParseDataType.tryParsLong(objMMC.getMobileNo()), objMMC.getBody(), objMMC.getOpCode());
        smsOut.setHttpHeader(httpHeader);
        smsOut.setSmsProvider(AppConstants.getSmsProviderSendPost());
        String messageId = smsHelper.sendSms(smsOut); \\this object is injected
        if (ParseDataType.tryParsLong(messageId) > 1000)
            LOGGER_SUMMARY.info(objMMC.getMobileNo() + "->" + MESSAGE_SMS_SENT_SUCCESS + ": " + messageId +
                    " from line: " + AppConstants.getSmsProviderSendPost().getSmsNumber() + " OpCode: " + objMMC.getOpCode());
        else
            LOGGER_SUMMARY.error(objMMC.getMobileNo() + "->" + MESSAGE_SMS_SENT_FAILED + ": " +
                    EnumSMSErrorCodes.getDescriptionForCode((int) ParseDataType.tryParsInt(messageId)) + " OpCode: " +
                    objMMC.getOpCode() + " from line: " + AppConstants.getSmsProviderSendPost().getSmsNumber());
        LOGGER_POSTED_REQUEST.info(objMMC.getMobileNo() + "-> messageId: " + messageId + ", form MMC(RemoteAddr:" + remoteAddr +
                " ,remoteHost:" + remoteHost + "): MMC Message Body[" +
                objMMC.getBody().replaceAll("\n", " ") + "]");
        response.resume(messageId);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        response.resume("-1");
        LOGGER_SUMMARY.error("EXCEPTION IN POST SmsGatewayJaxrsConfig FROM MMC: " + objMMC.getMobileNo() + " OpCode: " +
                objMMC.getOpCode() + " ,message is:" + ex.getMessage());
        LOGGER_STACK_TRACE.error("EXCEPTION IN POST SmsGatewayJaxrsConfig FROM MMC: " + objMMC.getMobileNo(), ex);
    }
}
```

I need help to find the root cause of this thread stuck.
here is the thread dump report in following:

```
[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '24' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'
priority:1 - threadId:0x000000002b5ad800 - nativeId:0x152c - nativeId (decimal):5420 - state:RUNNABLE
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:140)
at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:237)
at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:355)
at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:227)
at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readHeaderLine(Http1Codec.java:215)
at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189)
at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:88)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
at client.okhttp.CommonOkHttpClient.doGetRequest(CommonOkHttpClient.java:66)
at client.okhttp.ProviderClient.doSendSmsRequest(ProviderClient.java:107)
at client.okhttp.ProviderClient.doSendSmsRequest(ProviderClient.java:95)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor240.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.MethodInvocationInvocationContext.proceed(MethodInvocationInvocationContext.java:101)
at ir.bki.util.produces.loggers.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.intercept(LoggingInterceptor.java:64)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor175.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.JeeInterceptorInterceptor.invoke(JeeInterceptorInterceptor.java:94)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.MethodInvocationInvocationContext.proceed(MethodInvocationInvocationContext.java:101)
at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.JeeInterceptorInterceptor.invoke(JeeInterceptorInterceptor.java:101)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.MethodInvocationInvocationContext.proceed(MethodInvocationInvocationContext.java:101)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor160.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.JeeInterceptorInterceptor.invoke(JeeInterceptorInterceptor.java:94)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy245.doSendSmsRequest(Unknown Source)
at client.okhttp.ProviderClient_siljso_NoIntfViewImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionLocalMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionLocalMethodInvoker.java:33)
at client.okhttp.ProviderClient_siljso_NoIntfViewImpl.doSendSmsRequest(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor239.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:436)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:127)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:67)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
at client.okhttp.ProviderClient$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.doSendSmsRequest(Unknown Source)
at client.SmsHelper.sendSms(SmsHelper.java:53)
at service.sms.exchange.SmsSend.postSMS(SmsSend.java:87)
at service.sms.exchange.SmsSend$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.postSMS$$super(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor297.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.TerminalAroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceedInternal(TerminalAroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:49)
at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:77)
at ir.bki.util.produces.loggers.interceptors.LoggableCasheInterceptor.interceptDatabaseMethod(LoggableCasheInterceptor.java:63)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor176.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.reader.SimpleInterceptorInvocation$SimpleMethodInvocation.invoke(SimpleInterceptorInvocation.java:74)
at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.NonTerminalAroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceedInternal(NonTerminalAroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:64)
at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:77)
at ir.bki.util.produces.loggers.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.intercept(LoggingInterceptor.java:64)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor175.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.reader.SimpleInterceptorInvocation$SimpleMethodInvocation.invoke(SimpleInterceptorInvocation.java:74)
at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.executeAroundInvoke(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:84)
at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.executeInterception(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:72)
at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.invoke(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:56)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.invoke(CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.java:79)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.invoke(CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.java:68)
at service.sms.exchange.SmsSend$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.postSMS(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor296.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$VoidOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:143)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3683)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1686)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1646)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
```

Comment: OKHTTP parameters sets as follow:

  `  protected static OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new Builder()
            .connectTimeout(TIMEOUT_CONNECT_OKHTTP, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(TIMEOUT_WRITE_OKHTTP, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(TIMEOUT_READ_OKHTTP, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();`

Answer (score 1):

Your threads are waiting for a response from your remote service. Add a timeout to your outgoing connection to not wait for a long time after a response that will never come.

Comment: thanks for your answer <br>

as I said, I use the okhttp to call another RESTFull service and I set their parameters as follow:

  `  protected static OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new Builder()
            .connectTimeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();`

Comment: You should take severa thread dumps to see if the JVM stays stuck on this code or if it running something else. A stuck thread means that the the thread is running for a long time (> 10 minutes as default) but it can be because it has many code to run.